# Multiple custom UITableViewCell using the same TableViewCell prototype

Tags: ios, uitableview

I like to see what are my options to do this in iOS7. I have a TableViewCell prototype with identifier `TableViewCell_RightDetailID` in an `UITableViewController`. I also have two other custom tableviewcell classes that would like to use this prototype.

Any ideas on how to do this? Not sure if its possible?

```
@interface TableViewCellA : UITableViewCell
@interface TableViewCellB : UITableViewCell
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work:

TableViewController.m

```
#import "TVC.h"
#import "TableViewCellA.h"
#import "TableViewCellB.h"

@implementation TVC

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 2;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        TableViewCellA *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableViewCell_RightDetailID"];
        // title, detaillabel etc
        return cell;

    }
    else
    {
        TableViewCellB *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableViewCell_RightDetailID"];
        // TO DO
        return cell;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: This won't work.  Even though you're declaring `cell` to be of type `TableViewCellA` (or B) the actual class of the instantiated cell is determined by the storyboard.

Comment: Ok, I was not sure if this has to be, but you are right.
Why don't create two reusable cells with different identifiers and different classes. This shouldn't be a problem..

Comment: That's essentially my answer.  In this case it seems benign enough since the cells have a very simple layout.  It can become an issue if you have multiple variations with complex layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Since the class of the cell is set in the prototype in the storyboard, it's not possible to change it short of copying the prototype in the storyboard (and using distinct reuse identifiers)

This actually might be an argument for doing the layout in code and registering all three classes via `[UITableView registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:]`